# How do you get second window in Texture Paint Mode

Tags: texturing, 3d-view, texture-painting, windows

I'm using Blender 2.92 and whenever I go to `Texture Paint` mode, I'm only seeing the flat texture. How can I create a second window and see the model as well?

Apologies for the noob question, but no answers are online.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.

1. Go to `Texture Paint` mode
2. Copy a new window by mousing over the top right of the window and then dragging left to create another window on the right
3. Change that window to show your model by click `Editor Type` in the very top left corner of the window and select `3D Viewport`. Then to the right of that select `Texture Paint`